# Drush Config import not working after Site-install Standard. There were errors validating the config synchronization

Tags: configuration, 9, installation

I am Upgrading `Drupal 8.9` to `Drupal 9.2` and it's installed but when am I trying run `-y config-import` then getting error

> [error]  Drupal\Core\Config\ConfigImporterException: There were errors validating the config synchronization.
> Cannot change the install profile from  to standard once Drupal is installed.
> Unable to install the standard module since it does not exist. in Drupal\Core\Config\ConfigImporter->validate()
> (line 750 of /web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Config/ConfigImporter.php).

The import failed due to the following reasons:
Cannot change the install profile from  to standard once Drupal is installed.
Unable to install the standard module since it
does not exist.

I verified my *core.extension.yml* file there is already written:

```
module:
   standard: 1000
profile: standard
```

And try to add `$settings['install_profile'] = 'standard';` to settings.php.

I tried with this reference as well  https://www.drupal.org/node/2952947  but didn't get any solution.

Comment: Yes, you can't use settings.php anymore. The question is why you don't have a profile defined in the active configuration. Newer D8 sites should have had this when installed. For older sites there was an update hook. Obviously you can't change this via importing config. The correct reference by the way: https://www.drupal.org/node/2538996

Comment: Don't use the code in the change record, use one of the ones from the comments (or the profile switcher module)

Comment: I tried with profile switcher as well and went through this reference doc "https://www.drupal.org/node/2538996" . I tried hook_update_N()  but unable to resolve the error.

Comment: Can anyone look into it or suggest, how can I resolve it ? still I am unable to get any solution.